# Matlab: Total memory usage returned by "whos" doesn't match "Memory used by Matlab" returned by "memory"

Tags: matlab, memory-management

I have a script that sometimes crashes and sometimes returns an "out of memory" message. While investigating, I discovered that when adding up the memory allocated to my variables, as returned by "whos", I get a total of about 380 MB. On the other hand, "memory" returns 1196 MB as the total memory used by Matlab. I know the program itself takes up some memory, but I'm thinking it should not be as much as 800 MB. Does anyone have an idea of where the rest of my memory is being used? Thanks in advance for any advice.

- Steve

Comment: What do you get from memory in a freshly opened matlab?

Comment: Freshly opened shows about 300-320 MB used.

Answer (score 1):

The rest of the memory is probably used by the MATLAB program itself.  Unfortunately, MATLAB could consume 800 MB, since it probably has memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks. It seems as though you are right. It's strange, though, as continue to work through my script one block at a time, the amount of memory used increases steadily, even though I am deleting no-longer-used variables and running "pack" from the command line between executing blocks.